# Workorders created locally on the device

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

As per IBM's APAR IV71868

> There is a new property - si.device.createdLocallyLimit in worklight.properties that manages the maximum of workorders kept by on the device. By default it's set to 10. Once you get past that count, the workorders will be removed automatically from the device.

What is the criteria for removing these workorders? Is it on internal row id in the local database or is it based on a sort order?

e.g. If I create workorder ce-101123 which comes after workorder ce-9834. But if the removal works based on wonum then ce-101123 will be removed instead of ce-9834 as that will be sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be based on how you sort the order, but you could modify the _updateCreatedLocally function found in _ServerDataDownloadManager.js to do a sort on the store based on some criteria before it starts the remove process.